# Xtragrid column checkedit check all header

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

,Hi guys,

I am using Devexpress Xtragrid in winforms.

I have a **checkedit(checkbox) column.**

**I want to put a column header and if i click to header i want to set all rows checked.**

However ,

In this example,

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsSelection_ShowCheckBoxSelectorInColumnHeadertopic

there is no property as

```
"ShowCheckBoxSelectorInColumnHeader".
```

What property use in order to achieve checkbox column header to active ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be one, post your code. It will be in `gridview.OptionsSelection.ShowCheckBoxSelectorInColumnHeader`

Comment: ShowCheckBoxSelectorInColumnHeader does not appear .

Comment: I guess you're trying with `GridControl`, you need to try with `GridView` instead. If not post your attempt.

Comment: gridcontrol does not have optionsselection. i am trying gridview. is there any problem about dll or something?

Comment: Which version you're using? Am not sure whether old version have this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property was introduced in DevExpress v13.2 in the context of [Web Style Row Selection feature](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKNH7cLnKMA).
Thus, update your DevExpress to the latest version.

Comment: Sure, that there is no this feature in v13.1