# Unable to select single column's values in WinForms DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

I have `DevExpress GridControl` with one default `GridView` to show the records in my form. I have bound the values to `GridControl` from SQL Database table. Here, I want to select the single column's values as array or something similar using mouse click with any key combination. I have googled and get the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649791/xtragrid-column-checkedit-check-all-header) to select multiple rows using `CheckBox` column.

But, my scenario is different. I would like to select single column's values as array.

**EDIT:**
I am also looking for an answer which needs to be *highlight all cell values when clicked with any key combination in column header* (similar like we have an option in Microsoft Excel).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don' think that there is a built-in method to do that. You can loop through rows and use [`ColumnView.GetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowCellValue.method(sFKk0Q)) to access the cells from a particular column.

Something like this should work:

```
//get the number of rows in a target view (gridView for example)
int rowsCount = gridView.DataRowCount;
//allocate an array for column values
var columnValues = new object[rowsCount];
//get column by field name
var column = gridView.Columns["ColumnName"];
//loop through rows and populate column values
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++)
{
    columnValues[rowIndex] = gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowIndex, column);
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can refer to the official example in DevExpress knowledge base: [How to select cells under by clicking the GridBand or the column header](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E490/how-to-select-cells-under-by-clicking-the-gridband-or-the-column-header).

What you'll need to do:

- handle `MouseDown` event on a gridview;
- use `CalcHitInfo` to detect a click on a column header (check out this question: "[Detect the column header region in the mouse down event of a grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q424792/detect-the-column-header-region-in-the-mouse-down-event-of-a-grid))" and this knowledge base article: "[Hit Information](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/7557/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Miscellaneous/Hit-Information)";
- then use [`GridView.SelectCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.SelectCell.method(QrP7gg)) to update selection

  ```
  private void SelectCells(GridColumn column) {
      for (int i = 0; i < column.View.RowCount; i++)
          column.View.SelectCell(i, column);
  }
  ```

If your grid view is editable, cell editors might steal the `MouseDown` event. In this case, you'll need to reconfigure the grid as described in this discussion: [GridView - How to catch a cell click?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q406257/gridview-how-to-catch-a-cell-click)

Comment: So, I need to use the above solution on Cell header click event or some thing like this?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu yes, you can handle mouse down and use `CalcHitInfo` to handle a click on a column header (check out [this support question](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B968/xtragrid-column-header-click) for example). Then you can use this method to get values from a column. I was not sure about your particular scenario and decided to keep my answer generic.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question, which need additional option as well. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Sorry for late reply. Let me try your's solution.